# Changing shape of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape (X,2):

```
array([[-0.42766381, -0.14222465],
   [ 0.14321355, -0.11368064],
   [ 0.0004935 , -0.11368064],
   [ 0.0004935 , -0.08513739],
   [ 0.1432126 , -0.02805013],
   [ 0.0004935 ,  0.05758133],
   [ 0.14321165,  0.05758095],
   [ 0.1432107 ,  0.08612439],
   [ 0.0004935 ,  0.08612439],...
```

I would like to change the shape of this array to (X,3,2):

```
array([[[-0.42766381, -0.14222465]
    [ 0.14321355, -0.11368064]
    [ 0.0004935 , -0.11368064]]

   [[ 0.0004935 , -0.08513739]
    [ 0.1432126 , -0.02805013]
    [ 0.0004935 ,  0.05758133]]

   [[ 0.14321165,  0.05758095]
    [ 0.1432107 ,  0.08612439]
    [ 0.0004935 ,  0.08612439]]]
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: `A.reshape(-1,3,2)` should do it (where `A` is you array)

Comment: Do you want `(X,3,2)` or (X/3,3,2)`?  Same number of elements or increase the number?

Answer (score 0):

This is exaclty what the numpy.reshape() method is for. Assuming that your array is A, then:
    A.reshape(-1,3,2) will do it.